# Does a program used to extend an existing program count as achieving interoperability for decompilation?

Tags: copyright, software, european-union

From the [EU 2009/24/EC directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32009L0024&from=EN#d1e358-16-1) on the legal protection of computer programs, decompilation of programs is allowed under the following term:

> 1. The authorisation of the rightholder shall not be required where reproduction of the code and translation of its form within the meaning of points (a) and (b) of Article 4(1) are indispensable to obtain the information necessary to achieve the interoperability of an independently created computer program with other programs, provided that the following conditions are met: ...

I'm developing software to extend games made with a certain engine, this software is automatically loaded by the engine when present and does runtime patches to extend the existing behaviour. These games are usually distributed without any explicit license.

However there are certain differences between each program, and if the source is not distributed, decompilation is necessary to find out where exactly my software should apply the patches.

The above law says that authorization from the copyright holder for decompilation is not required when getting

> ... information necessary to achieve the interoperability of an independently created computer program with other programs ...

From the above meaning, can my software be the "independently created computer program" which is achieving interoperability with the original program that'd fall under "other programs" ?